# Web Portal with Desktop/Mobile Version. What are recommendations?

Tags: angularjs, mobile, web-applications

I am thinking develop a web portal with a desktop. This portal will be used in mobile phones and as one of its requirements is to work offline and when you are online, synchronize data, I think it must be a native version for Android and iOS. What is the framework that advise to develop one application and generate an Android application and other iOS?

The idea is to try to enjoy the same logic of development for desktop and mobile. I have experience with AngularJS but do not know whether it will help in the mobile.

Comment: I personally would use Bootstrap for the desktop / mobile situation, the offline thing is no problem u can use IndexedDB or WebSql(deprecated) to store the information. I can only recommend to use Ionic Framework too. I am currently building a hybrid app (android / ios / windows) with angular / cordova / ionic which is partial offline and stores data which is later synchronized.

Comment: depending on the Size of data stored offline even Localstorage can be enough.

Comment: Soo you are using Ionic Framework for mobile version and for desktop version, what you are using?

Comment: ionic can be used for both but i would suggest u build a responsive website with bootstrap (makes it easier). which works for desktop and mobile and use Ionic and Angular.